# Adview Below FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am switching through `Fragments` from my main activity. At the moment I am calling a new `AdView` from each `Fragment` but I only want to call one `AdView` from the main activity which shows across all the `Fragments`.

Now I just need to know how to get the `AdView` not to show inside the `FrameLayout` because now it is blocking the content at the bottom.

So how can I get the `AdView` outside/below the content in the `FrameLayout` ?

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainFrame">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change your top `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`, then add `android:layout_weight="1"` on the sub-`RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use  only single `Relative Layout` as `Root Layout` and then use `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` in `Frame Layout`.

*Here is xml code* .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]